# Is it possible to read off CMD without user input?

Tags: command-line, java, cmd.exe, minecraft

I was wondering if there was any way to read straight off CMD on windows without having inputs from a user using Java.

I'm running a Minecraft server and want to create certain types of automatic responses if events occur via the console.

I apologize if this is an obvious question!

Comment: I can't understand well your question, could try to explain us a little better?  Can your need solved by a **script**?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'm trying to read off the windows command line which updates with text by the Minecraft server and then interpret that with java (or maybe some other language) and then input a new command based on the interpretation of the text from the console.
Or maybe more simply put I'm trying to read off the windows command line with Java and then inputting new commands into the command line with java.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question on StackOverflow that seems to be the answer for your issue, look at link bellow:

[Executing PowerShell Commands in Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545611/executing-powershell-commands-in-java-program)